# Объединение нескольких массивов в один ассоциативный

Tags: php, массивы, объединение

Есть несколько массивов, содержащих различные данные
В первом массиве содержатся некие ID(122, 215 и тд)
Во втором Имя
В третьем фамилия
Причем содержатся так, что id[0] = 333 это айди пользователя name[0], каким бы оно ни было
Нужно объединить это все в один ассоциативный массив так, чтоб вышло

```
[0] => (id[0], name[0], lastname[0], ...)
[1] => (id[1], name[1], lastname[1], ...)
...
```

Comment: добавьте к вашему вопросу `var_dump` ваших исходных массивов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($id); $i++) {
  $data[] = [
    'id' => $id[$i],
    'name' => $name[$i],
    'lastname' => $lastname[$i]
  ];
}
var_dump($data);
```